# Why do react MobileStoreButtons have different shapes?

Tags: reactjs, button

With the React react-mobile-store-button component I try to implement the mobile store buttons. Problem is that they have different shape and I can't find any reason why this should be the case. I found a minimal example where this is also the case: https://codesandbox.io/s/zok0u?file=/src/index.js

[image]

How can I make them have the same shape?

Comment: The library uses png for google play and svg for app store.

Comment: Weird... Any other suggestions for other libraries?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:** The issue you're experiencing is due to the usage of images to display buttons in the package. I submitted a pull request (PR) to address this problem, and it was merged into the GitHub repository. However, the changes have not been published to the NPM package.

**Solution:** To resolve this issue and offer more customization options for buttons, I created a new package called **[react-mobile-app-button](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mobile-app-button?activeTab=readme)**. This package allows you to customize various aspects of the button, such as design, theme, size, title, and more.

[image]

Example: **[Sandobx](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mobile-app-button-858grd)**

By using this new package, you can have greater control over button customization and ensure that your app's buttons are displayed correctly.

Feel free to check it out and use it in your project. If you have any further questions or encounter any issues, please don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

The library uses png for google play and svg for app store.

You could use individual svg's instead of a library.

```js
const GooglePlayStoreIcon = () => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5435.8 1604">
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M5234.4 1604h-5033C90.4 1604 0 1513.6 0 1403.5v-1203C0 90 90.4 0 201.4 0h5033c110.9 0 201.4 90 201.4 200.5v1203c0 110.1-90.5 200.5-201.4 200.5z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <path
      fill="#a6a6a6"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M5234.4 32.1c93.1 0 169.3 75.7 169.3 168.4v1203c0 92.7-75.7 168.4-169.3 168.4h-5033c-93.1 0-169.3-75.7-169.3-168.4v-1203c0-92.7 75.7-168.4 169.3-168.4h5033zm0-32.1h-5033C90.4 0 0 90.4 0 200.5v1203C0 1514 90.4 1604 201.4 1604h5033c110.9 0 201.4-90 201.4-200.5v-1203C5435.8 90.4 5345.3 0 5234.4 0z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <path
      fill="#fff"
      d="M2863.6 530.6c-36.3 0-66.9-12.7-91.1-37.7-24-24.3-37.4-57.8-36.8-92 0-36.5 12.4-67.4 36.8-91.9 24.1-25 54.7-37.7 91-37.7 35.9 0 66.5 12.7 91.1 37.7 24.4 25.3 36.8 56.2 36.8 91.9-.4 36.6-12.8 67.5-36.8 91.9-24.1 25.2-54.7 37.8-91 37.8zm-1080.1 0c-35.5 0-66.3-12.5-91.5-37.2-25-24.6-37.7-55.7-37.7-92.4s12.7-67.8 37.7-92.4c24.7-24.7 55.5-37.2 91.5-37.2 17.6 0 34.7 3.5 51.1 10.6 16.1 6.9 29.2 16.3 38.9 27.8l2.4 2.9-27.1 26.6-2.8-3.3c-15.3-18.2-35.8-27.1-62.9-27.1-24.2 0-45.3 8.6-62.7 25.6-17.5 17.1-26.4 39.5-26.4 66.6s8.9 49.5 26.4 66.6c17.4 17 38.5 25.6 62.7 25.6 25.8 0 47.5-8.6 64.4-25.6 10-10 16.2-24 18.4-41.7H1779v-37.4h124.2l.5 3.4c.9 6.3 1.8 12.8 1.8 18.8 0 34.5-10.4 62.4-31 83-23.4 24.4-54 36.8-91 36.8zm1436.1-5.3h-38.3L3064 337.6l1 33.8v153.8h-38.3V276.7h43.7l1.2 1.9 110.3 176.8-1-33.7v-145h38.7v248.6zm-643.8 0H2537V314.1h-67.3v-37.4H2643v37.4h-67.3v211.2zm-137.7 0h-38.7V276.7h38.7v248.6zm-217.5 0h-38.7V314.1h-67.3v-37.4h173.3v37.4h-67.3v211.2zm-130.5-.4h-148.4V276.7h148.4v37.4h-109.6v68.2h98.9v37h-98.9v68.2h109.6v37.4zm710.8-57.7c17.3 17.3 38.3 26 62.7 26 25.1 0 45.6-8.5 62.7-26 17-17 25.6-39.3 25.6-66.2s-8.6-49.3-25.5-66.2c-17.3-17.3-38.4-26-62.7-26-25.1 0-45.6 8.5-62.6 26-17 17-25.6 39.3-25.6 66.2s8.5 49.3 25.4 66.2z"
    ></path>
    <path
      fill="#fff"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M2732.1 872.4c-94.5 0-171.1 71.7-171.1 170.6 0 98 77.1 170.6 171.1 170.6 94.5 0 171.1-72.2 171.1-170.6 0-98.9-76.6-170.6-171.1-170.6zm0 273.6c-51.7 0-96.2-42.8-96.2-103.4 0-61.5 44.6-103.4 96.2-103.4 51.7 0 96.2 41.9 96.2 103.4.1 61-44.5 103.4-96.2 103.4zm-373.3-273.6c-94.5 0-171.1 71.7-171.1 170.6 0 98 77.1 170.6 171.1 170.6 94.5 0 171.1-72.2 171.1-170.6 0-98.9-76.7-170.6-171.1-170.6zm0 273.6c-51.7 0-96.2-42.8-96.2-103.4 0-61.5 44.6-103.4 96.2-103.4 51.7 0 96.2 41.9 96.2 103.4 0 61-44.5 103.4-96.2 103.4zm-444.2-221.5v72.2h173.3c-5.3 40.5-18.7 70.4-39.2 90.9-25.4 25.4-64.6 53-133.7 53-106.5 0-189.8-86-189.8-192.5s83.3-192.5 189.8-192.5c57.5 0 99.4 22.7 130.5 51.7l51.2-51.2c-43.2-41.4-100.7-73.1-181.3-73.1-146.1 0-268.7 119-268.7 264.7 0 146.1 122.5 264.7 268.7 264.7 78.9 0 138.1-25.8 184.9-74.4 47.7-47.7 62.8-115 62.8-169.3 0-16.9-1.3-32.1-4-45h-244.6c.1-.1.1.8.1.8zm1816.9 56.2C3717.2 942.4 3674 872 3585.4 872c-87.8 0-160.8 69.1-160.8 170.6 0 95.8 72.2 170.6 169.3 170.6 78 0 123.4-47.7 142.1-75.7l-57.9-38.8c-19.2 28.5-45.9 47.2-83.8 47.2-38.3 0-65.1-17.4-82.9-51.7l228.1-94.5c0 .1-8-19-8-19zm-232.6 57c-1.8-65.9 51.2-99.4 89.1-99.4 29.9 0 54.8 14.7 63.3 36.1l-152.4 63.3zM3313.6 1203h74.9V701.8h-74.9V1203zm-123-292.7h-2.7c-16.9-20.1-49-38.3-90-38.3-85.1 0-163.5 74.9-163.5 171.1 0 95.8 78 169.8 163.5 169.8 40.5 0 73.1-18.3 90-38.8h2.7v24.5c0 65.1-34.8 100.2-90.9 100.2-45.9 0-74.4-33-86-60.6l-65.1 27.2c18.7 45 68.6 100.7 151 100.7 87.8 0 162.2-51.7 162.2-177.8V882.2H3191v28.1h-.4zm-86 235.7c-51.7 0-94.9-43.2-94.9-102.9 0-60.2 43.2-103.8 94.9-103.8 51.2 0 90.9 44.1 90.9 103.8.5 59.7-39.6 102.9-90.9 102.9zm977.6-444.2h-179.1V1203h74.9v-189.8h104.3c82.9 0 164.4-60.1 164.4-155.5s-81.2-155.9-164.5-155.9zm2.2 241.4h-106.5v-172h106.5c56.1 0 87.8 46.3 87.8 86 0 39.3-32.1 86-87.8 86zm462.5-71.7c-54.4 0-110.5 24.1-133.7 76.6l66.4 27.6c14.3-27.6 40.5-37 68.2-37 38.8 0 78 23.2 78.9 64.6v5.3c-13.4-7.6-42.8-19.2-78-19.2-71.7 0-144.4 39.2-144.4 112.7 0 67.3 58.8 110.5 124.3 110.5 50.3 0 78-22.7 95.3-49h2.7v38.8h72.2v-192c0-89.4-66.4-138.9-151.9-138.9zm-9.4 274.5c-24.5 0-58.8-12-58.8-42.8 0-38.8 42.8-53.5 79.3-53.5 33 0 48.6 7.1 68.2 16.9-5.4 45-43.4 79-88.7 79.4zm424.7-263.8l-86 217.4h-2.7l-89.1-217.4h-80.6l133.7 303.9-76.2 168.9h78L5045 882.2h-82.8zM4288 1203h74.9V701.8H4288V1203z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <linearGradient
      id="a"
      x1="1682.108"
      x2="1624.292"
      y1="1339.478"
      y2="1309.634"
      gradientTransform="matrix(11.64 0 0 -22.55 -18705.596 30554.37)"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <stop offset="0" stopColor="#00a0ff"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.007" stopColor="#00a1ff"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.26" stopColor="#00beff"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.512" stopColor="#00d2ff"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.76" stopColor="#00dfff"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stopColor="#00e3ff"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path
      fill="url(#a)"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M418.4 302.1c-11.6 12.5-18.3 31.6-18.3 56.6v886.7c0 25 6.7 44.1 18.7 56.1l3.1 2.7 496.8-496.8v-11.1L421.5 299.4l-3.1 2.7z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <linearGradient
      id="b"
      x1="1712.662"
      x2="1606.561"
      y1="1274.838"
      y2="1274.838"
      gradientTransform="matrix(9.145 0 0 -7.7 -14305.538 10618.251)"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <stop offset="0" stopColor="#ffe000"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.409" stopColor="#ffbd00"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.775" stopColor="orange"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stopColor="#ff9c00"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path
      fill="url(#b)"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M1084 973.5L918.3 807.8v-11.6L1084 630.5l3.6 2.2 196 111.4c56.1 31.6 56.1 83.8 0 115.8l-196 111.4-3.6 2.2z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <linearGradient
      id="c"
      x1="1707.441"
      x2="1646.682"
      y1="1290.047"
      y2="1211.223"
      gradientTransform="matrix(15.02 0 0 -11.5775 -24650.229 15829.648)"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <stop offset="0" stopColor="#ff3a44"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stopColor="#c31162"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path
      fill="url(#c)"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M1087.6 971.3L918.3 802l-499.9 499.9c18.3 19.6 49 21.8 83.3 2.7l585.9-333.3"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <linearGradient
      id="d"
      x1="1660.636"
      x2="1687.767"
      y1="1365.668"
      y2="1330.45"
      gradientTransform="matrix(15.02 0 0 -11.5715 -24650.229 15809.992)"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <stop offset="0" stopColor="#32a071"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.069" stopColor="#2da771"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.476" stopColor="#15cf74"></stop>
      <stop offset="0.801" stopColor="#06e775"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stopColor="#00f076"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path
      fill="url(#d)"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M1087.6 632.7L501.7 299.9c-34.3-19.6-65.1-16.9-83.3 2.7L918.3 802l169.3-169.3z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
    ></path>
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M1084 967.7l-581.9 330.6c-32.5 18.7-61.5 17.4-80.2.4l-3.1 3.1 3.1 2.7c18.7 16.9 47.7 18.3 80.2-.4L1088 971.3l-4-3.6z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      opacity="0.2"
    ></path>
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M1283.6 854.1l-200.1 113.6 3.6 3.6 196-111.4c28.1-16 41.9-37 41.9-57.9-1.7 19.2-16 37.4-41.4 52.1z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      opacity="0.12"
    ></path>
    <path
      fill="#fff"
      fillRule="evenodd"
      d="M501.7 305.7l781.9 444.2c25.4 14.3 39.7 33 41.9 52.1 0-20.9-13.8-41.9-41.9-57.9L501.7 299.9c-56.1-32.1-101.6-5.3-101.6 58.8v5.8c0-64.2 45.5-90.5 101.6-58.8z"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      opacity="0.25"
    ></path>
  </svg>
);

const AppStoreIcon = () => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 135 40">
    <path
      fill="#A6A6A6"
      d="M130.197 40H4.729A4.74 4.74 0 0 1 0 35.267V4.726A4.733 4.733 0 0 1 4.729 0h125.468C132.803 0 135 2.12 135 4.726v30.541c0 2.605-2.197 4.733-4.803 4.733z"
    />
    <path d="M134.032 35.268a3.83 3.83 0 0 1-3.834 3.83H4.729a3.835 3.835 0 0 1-3.839-3.83V4.725A3.84 3.84 0 0 1 4.729.89h125.468a3.834 3.834 0 0 1 3.834 3.835l.001 30.543z" />
    <path
      fill="#FFF"
      d="M30.128 19.784c-.029-3.223 2.639-4.791 2.761-4.864-1.511-2.203-3.853-2.504-4.676-2.528-1.967-.207-3.875 1.177-4.877 1.177-1.022 0-2.565-1.157-4.228-1.123-2.14.033-4.142 1.272-5.24 3.196-2.266 3.923-.576 9.688 1.595 12.859 1.086 1.553 2.355 3.287 4.016 3.226 1.625-.067 2.232-1.036 4.193-1.036 1.943 0 2.513 1.036 4.207.997 1.744-.028 2.842-1.56 3.89-3.127 1.255-1.78 1.759-3.533 1.779-3.623-.041-.014-3.387-1.291-3.42-5.154zm-3.2-9.478c.874-1.093 1.472-2.58 1.306-4.089-1.265.056-2.847.875-3.758 1.944-.806.942-1.526 2.486-1.34 3.938 1.421.106 2.88-.717 3.792-1.793zm26.717 21.198h-2.271l-1.244-3.909h-4.324l-1.185 3.909H42.41l4.284-13.308h2.646l4.305 13.308zm-3.89-5.549L48.63 22.48c-.119-.355-.342-1.191-.671-2.507h-.04a96.75 96.75 0 0 1-.632 2.507l-1.105 3.475h3.573zm14.907.633c0 1.632-.441 2.922-1.323 3.869-.79.843-1.771 1.264-2.942 1.264-1.264 0-2.172-.454-2.725-1.362h-.04v5.055H55.5V25.067c0-1.026-.027-2.079-.079-3.159h1.875l.119 1.521h.04c.711-1.146 1.79-1.718 3.238-1.718 1.132 0 2.077.447 2.833 1.342.758.896 1.136 2.074 1.136 3.535zm-2.172.078c0-.934-.21-1.704-.632-2.31-.461-.632-1.08-.948-1.856-.948-.526 0-1.004.176-1.431.523-.428.35-.708.807-.839 1.373-.066.264-.099.48-.099.65v1.6c0 .698.214 1.287.642 1.768s.984.721 1.668.721c.803 0 1.428-.31 1.875-.928.448-.619.672-1.435.672-2.449zm13.209-.078c0 1.632-.441 2.922-1.324 3.869-.789.843-1.77 1.264-2.941 1.264-1.264 0-2.172-.454-2.724-1.362h-.04v5.055h-2.132V25.067c0-1.026-.027-2.079-.079-3.159h1.875l.119 1.521h.04c.71-1.146 1.789-1.718 3.238-1.718 1.131 0 2.076.447 2.834 1.342.755.896 1.134 2.074 1.134 3.535zm-2.172.078c0-.934-.211-1.704-.633-2.31-.461-.632-1.078-.948-1.855-.948a2.22 2.22 0 0 0-1.432.523c-.428.35-.707.807-.838 1.373-.065.264-.099.48-.099.65v1.6c0 .698.214 1.287.64 1.768.428.48.984.721 1.67.721.803 0 1.428-.31 1.875-.928.448-.619.672-1.435.672-2.449zm14.512 1.106c0 1.132-.393 2.053-1.182 2.764-.867.777-2.074 1.165-3.625 1.165-1.432 0-2.58-.276-3.449-.829l.494-1.777c.936.566 1.963.85 3.082.85.803 0 1.428-.182 1.877-.544.447-.362.67-.848.67-1.454 0-.54-.184-.995-.553-1.364-.367-.369-.98-.712-1.836-1.029-2.33-.869-3.494-2.142-3.494-3.816 0-1.094.408-1.991 1.225-2.689.814-.699 1.9-1.048 3.258-1.048 1.211 0 2.217.211 3.02.632l-.533 1.738c-.75-.408-1.598-.612-2.547-.612-.75 0-1.336.185-1.756.553a1.58 1.58 0 0 0-.533 1.205c0 .526.203.961.611 1.303.355.316 1 .658 1.936 1.027 1.145.461 1.986 1 2.527 1.618.539.616.808 1.387.808 2.307zm7.049-4.264h-2.35v4.659c0 1.185.414 1.777 1.244 1.777.381 0 .697-.033.947-.099l.059 1.619c-.42.157-.973.236-1.658.236-.842 0-1.5-.257-1.975-.77-.473-.514-.711-1.376-.711-2.587v-4.837h-1.4v-1.6h1.4v-1.757l2.094-.632v2.389h2.35v1.602zm10.603 3.119c0 1.475-.422 2.686-1.264 3.633-.883.975-2.055 1.461-3.516 1.461-1.408 0-2.529-.467-3.365-1.401s-1.254-2.113-1.254-3.534c0-1.487.43-2.705 1.293-3.652.861-.948 2.023-1.422 3.484-1.422 1.408 0 2.541.467 3.396 1.402.818.907 1.226 2.078 1.226 3.513zm-2.212.069c0-.885-.189-1.644-.572-2.277-.447-.766-1.086-1.148-1.914-1.148-.857 0-1.508.383-1.955 1.148-.383.634-.572 1.405-.572 2.317 0 .885.189 1.644.572 2.276.461.766 1.105 1.148 1.936 1.148.814 0 1.453-.39 1.914-1.168.393-.645.591-1.412.591-2.296zm9.142-2.913a3.702 3.702 0 0 0-.672-.059c-.75 0-1.33.283-1.738.85-.355.5-.533 1.132-.533 1.895v5.035h-2.131l.02-6.574c0-1.106-.027-2.113-.08-3.021h1.857l.078 1.836h.059c.225-.631.58-1.139 1.066-1.52a2.578 2.578 0 0 1 1.541-.514c.197 0 .375.014.533.039v2.033zm9.535 2.469a5 5 0 0 1-.078.967h-6.396c.025.948.334 1.673.928 2.173.539.447 1.236.671 2.092.671.947 0 1.811-.151 2.588-.454l.334 1.48c-.908.396-1.98.593-3.217.593-1.488 0-2.656-.438-3.506-1.313-.848-.875-1.273-2.05-1.273-3.524 0-1.447.395-2.652 1.186-3.613.828-1.026 1.947-1.539 3.355-1.539 1.383 0 2.43.513 3.141 1.539.563.815.846 1.823.846 3.02zm-2.033-.553c.014-.632-.125-1.178-.414-1.639-.369-.593-.936-.889-1.699-.889-.697 0-1.264.289-1.697.869-.355.461-.566 1.014-.631 1.658h4.441zM49.05 10.009c0 1.177-.353 2.063-1.058 2.658-.653.549-1.581.824-2.783.824-.596 0-1.106-.026-1.533-.078V6.982c.557-.09 1.157-.136 1.805-.136 1.145 0 2.008.249 2.59.747.652.563.979 1.368.979 2.416zm-1.105.029c0-.763-.202-1.348-.606-1.756-.404-.407-.994-.611-1.771-.611-.33 0-.611.022-.844.068v4.889c.129.02.365.029.708.029.802 0 1.421-.223 1.857-.669s.656-1.096.656-1.95zm6.964.999c0 .725-.207 1.319-.621 1.785-.434.479-1.009.718-1.727.718-.692 0-1.243-.229-1.654-.689-.41-.459-.615-1.038-.615-1.736 0-.73.211-1.329.635-1.794s.994-.698 1.712-.698c.692 0 1.248.229 1.669.688.4.446.601 1.022.601 1.726zm-1.087.034c0-.435-.094-.808-.281-1.119-.22-.376-.533-.564-.94-.564-.421 0-.741.188-.961.564-.188.311-.281.69-.281 1.138 0 .435.094.808.281 1.119.227.376.543.564.951.564.4 0 .714-.191.94-.574.194-.317.291-.693.291-1.128zm8.943-2.352-1.475 4.714h-.96l-.611-2.047a15.32 15.32 0 0 1-.379-1.523h-.019a11.15 11.15 0 0 1-.379 1.523l-.649 2.047h-.971l-1.387-4.714h1.077l.533 2.241c.129.53.235 1.035.32 1.513h.019c.078-.394.207-.896.389-1.503l.669-2.25h.854l.641 2.202c.155.537.281 1.054.378 1.552h.029c.071-.485.178-1.002.32-1.552l.572-2.202h1.029zm5.433 4.714H67.15v-2.7c0-.832-.316-1.248-.95-1.248a.946.946 0 0 0-.757.343 1.217 1.217 0 0 0-.291.808v2.796h-1.048v-3.366c0-.414-.013-.863-.038-1.349h.921l.049.737h.029c.122-.229.304-.418.543-.569.284-.176.602-.265.95-.265.44 0 .806.142 1.097.427.362.349.543.87.543 1.562v2.824zm2.89 0h-1.047V6.556h1.047v6.877zm6.17-2.396c0 .725-.207 1.319-.621 1.785-.434.479-1.01.718-1.727.718-.693 0-1.244-.229-1.654-.689-.41-.459-.615-1.038-.615-1.736 0-.73.211-1.329.635-1.794s.994-.698 1.711-.698c.693 0 1.248.229 1.67.688.4.446.601 1.022.601 1.726zm-1.088.034c0-.435-.094-.808-.281-1.119-.219-.376-.533-.564-.939-.564-.422 0-.742.188-.961.564-.188.311-.281.69-.281 1.138 0 .435.094.808.281 1.119.227.376.543.564.951.564.4 0 .713-.191.939-.574.195-.317.291-.693.291-1.128zm6.16 2.362h-.941l-.078-.543h-.029c-.322.433-.781.65-1.377.65-.445 0-.805-.143-1.076-.427a1.339 1.339 0 0 1-.369-.96c0-.576.24-1.015.723-1.319.482-.304 1.16-.453 2.033-.446V10.3c0-.621-.326-.931-.979-.931-.465 0-.875.117-1.229.349l-.213-.688c.438-.271.979-.407 1.617-.407 1.232 0 1.85.65 1.85 1.95v1.736c0 .471.023.846.068 1.124zm-1.088-1.62v-.727c-1.156-.02-1.734.297-1.734.95 0 .246.066.43.201.553a.733.733 0 0 0 .512.184c.23 0 .445-.073.641-.218a.893.893 0 0 0 .38-.742zm7.043 1.62h-.93l-.049-.757h-.029c-.297.576-.803.864-1.514.864-.568 0-1.041-.223-1.416-.669s-.562-1.025-.562-1.736c0-.763.203-1.381.611-1.853.395-.44.879-.66 1.455-.66.633 0 1.076.213 1.328.64h.02V6.556h1.049v5.607c0 .459.012.882.037 1.27zm-1.086-1.988v-.786a1.194 1.194 0 0 0-.408-.965 1.03 1.03 0 0 0-.701-.257c-.391 0-.697.155-.922.466-.223.311-.336.708-.336 1.193 0 .466.107.844.322 1.135.227.31.533.465.916.465.344 0 .619-.129.828-.388.202-.239.301-.527.301-.863zm10.049-.408c0 .725-.207 1.319-.621 1.785-.434.479-1.008.718-1.727.718-.691 0-1.242-.229-1.654-.689-.41-.459-.615-1.038-.615-1.736 0-.73.211-1.329.635-1.794s.994-.698 1.713-.698c.691 0 1.248.229 1.668.688.4.446.601 1.022.601 1.726zm-1.086.034c0-.435-.094-.808-.281-1.119-.221-.376-.533-.564-.941-.564-.42 0-.74.188-.961.564-.188.311-.281.69-.281 1.138 0 .435.094.808.281 1.119.227.376.543.564.951.564.4 0 .715-.191.941-.574.193-.317.291-.693.291-1.128zm6.721 2.362h-1.047v-2.7c0-.832-.316-1.248-.951-1.248-.311 0-.562.114-.756.343s-.291.499-.291.808v2.796h-1.049v-3.366c0-.414-.012-.863-.037-1.349h.92l.049.737h.029a1.53 1.53 0 0 1 .543-.569c.285-.176.602-.265.951-.265.439 0 .805.142 1.096.427.363.349.543.87.543 1.562v2.824zm7.053-3.929h-1.154v2.29c0 .582.205.873.611.873.188 0 .344-.016.467-.049l.027.795c-.207.078-.479.117-.814.117-.414 0-.736-.126-.969-.378-.234-.252-.35-.676-.35-1.271V9.504h-.689v-.785h.689v-.864l1.027-.31v1.173h1.154v.786zm5.548 3.929h-1.049v-2.68c0-.845-.316-1.268-.949-1.268-.486 0-.818.245-1 .735a1.317 1.317 0 0 0-.049.377v2.835h-1.047V6.556h1.047v2.841h.02c.33-.517.803-.775 1.416-.775.434 0 .793.142 1.078.427.355.355.533.883.533 1.581v2.803zm5.723-2.58c0 .188-.014.346-.039.475h-3.143c.014.466.164.821.455 1.067.266.22.609.33 1.029.33.465 0 .889-.074 1.271-.223l.164.728c-.447.194-.973.291-1.582.291-.73 0-1.305-.215-1.721-.645-.418-.43-.625-1.007-.625-1.731 0-.711.193-1.303.582-1.775.406-.504.955-.756 1.648-.756.678 0 1.193.252 1.541.756.281.4.42.895.42 1.483zm-1-.271a1.411 1.411 0 0 0-.203-.805c-.182-.291-.459-.437-.834-.437a.995.995 0 0 0-.834.427 1.586 1.586 0 0 0-.311.815h2.182z"
    />
  </svg>
);
```

And use them as normal React components.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <GooglePlayStoreIcon />
        </a>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <AppStoreIcon />
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-platform-xpib4?file=/src/App.js:94-274)

Comment: Where do you have the SVGs from? Do Apple and Google provide them somewhere officially?

Comment: I did a google search and found them from wikipedia. They do provide official images – [Google](https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/), [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/); although not svg.